# The Choice of Java Constructor Replace is Ambiguous

Tags: javascript, rhino

I have that javascript code for a RhinoScript based framework:

```
function cleaner(tracker) {             
    var nRegex = new RegExp(reggo); 
    var regexMatch = tracker.match(nRegex);

    if (regexMatch == null || regexMatch == "" || regexMatch.length <= 0) {
        return tracker; 
    }

    tracker = tracker.replace(nRegex, "");      
    return tracker;     
}
```

However I get that exception for it:

> Exception: InternalError: The choice of Java constructor replace
>   matching JavaScript argument types (function,string) is ambiguous;
>   candidate constructors are:
>       class java.lang.String replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)
>       class java.lang.String replace(char,char) (#114)

I've tried something but didn't work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is Java/Javascript intergration via Rhino. Can you please post how you are invoking the JS function cleaner from Java?  What is the runtime type of the `tracker` argument passed into cleaner?

Comment: It is defined as var tracker = "" and then filled with a value from a webservice.

Comment: My best guess about your problem is that `tracker` is a `java.lang.String` which has its own `replace` method, and this does not behave the same as Javascript's `replace` function on JS strings.  You probably need to convert your string on input/output.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "tracker" in this case is a Java object but you expect it to be a JS string. You'll need to debug your other code to find out what it's being set to.

If the behavior was intentional and you really did want to choose one Java method or the other, you could do it by changing:

```
tracker = tracker.replace(nRegex, "");
```

To:

```
tracker = tracker['replace(char,char)'](nRegex, "");
// ...or...
tracker = tracker['replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)'](nRegex, "");
```

But of course, nRegex in this case was probably not meant to be a char or CharSequence.